# Seeking the answer to a scholastic situation

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to understand everything that I am learning, does rev_n *= 10; mean the reverse function under 10?

1. List item

> rev_n *= 10;

Comment: please post the whole code. It's unclear from what you are asking.

Comment: 'mean the reverse function under 10?'....kindly [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38556970/edit) your question so that it sounds clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what is `rev_n` in your question.

---

Anyway, `rev_n *= 10;` here means/is equivalent to:

```
rev_n = rev_n * 10;
```

This is mainly used to express the syntax that are already available in a shorter way.

***Note:*** In case you need a reference on [Shorthand Assignment Operator](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/shorthand.html).